# pyorient + Django : How should I create a model properly so that serializers can access them?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orientdb, pyorient

settings.py

```
from pyorient.ogm import declarative
Node = declarative.declarative_node()
Relationship = declarative.declarative_relationship()
```

models/user.py

```
from pyorient.ogm.property import *
from my_proj.settings import Node


class User(Node):
    email = String(unique=True)
    password = String()
```

serializers/register_serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers, validators
from users.models.user import User


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

I get the following exception

```
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute '_meta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add property to your model as,

```
class User(Node):
    email = String(unique=True)
    password = String()

    @property
    def my_property(self):
        return "my property data"
```

Then use `serializers.Serializer` instead of `serializers.ModelSerializer` as,

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    my_property = serializers.CharField()
```

Then, you will get serialized data as,

```
user_obj = User.object.get(id=1)
reg_serializer = RegisterSerializer(user_obj)
serialized_data = reg_serializer.data
```

Comment: for my case I really don't need something like User.object.get.. I only need serializers for swagger documentation auto generation.

Comment: I don't understand. Anyway, is there any problem?

Comment: No I don't have any problem. https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ this was my requirement and you resolved it using serializers.Serializer